# How to await an async Command for unit testing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, async-await, icommand

I'm trying to unit test a command but because its an async command, the test method goes into the assertions before the command is finished. I have looked up solutions to this problem and they all talk about creating an AsyncCommand interface etc which I don't want to do as I only need to await the commands for the unit tests purposes. So is there another solution to this which is simpler and doesn't require creating another interface etc?

this is my Command class:

```
   public class Command : ICommand
    {
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
          //exeute...
        }

        //other stuff....
    }
```

Thats the tested class:

```
pubic class MyClass
{
    private Command commandForTest;
    public Command CommandForTest
            {
                get
                {
                    if (commandForTest == null)
                    {
                        commandForTest = new Command(async (o) =>
                        {
                            if(someCondition)
                               await SomeMethod();
                             else
                               await AnotheMrthod();   

                        });
                    }
                    return commandForTest;
                }
            }
}
```

This is the test Method:

```
[TestMethod]
        public async Task Test()
{
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
    await Task.Run( () =>  myclass.CommandForTest.Execute());
    //Assert....
}
```

Comment: I haven't used much of commands, but you could try this page: https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/#

Comment: Do not test command, it's UI stuff. Rather make a public testable method which this command invokes.

Comment: You can't wait for what is never explicitly signaled as done. This is precisely why `Task` exists, and why `void` methods that are asynchronous can't effectively be tested. The inability to write a test is not a failing of your test, it's a failing of your code.

Answer (score 7):

> So is there another solution to this which is simpler and doesn't require creating another interface etc?

No and yes. There is another solution. It is **not** simpler. The simplest and most straightforward solution is to use an [`IAsyncCommand` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx). Or an `AsyncCommand` implementation that your unit test can cast the `ICommand` to (more brittle).

But if you want to go the hard way, then yes, you can technically detect when an `async void` method completes. You do this by writing your own [`SynchronizationContext` and listening to `OperationStarted` and `OperationCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx). You'll also need to build a queue of work and write a main loop that processes the queue.

I have a type that does this. It is called [`AsyncContext` and it is part of `AsyncEx`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/). Usage:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test() // note: not async
{
  MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
  AsyncContext.Run(() =>
  {
    myclass.CommandForTest.Execute();
  });
  //Assert....
}
```

Again, I strongly recommend using `IAsyncCommand`. The real problem is that the core MVVM types are insufficient. So most people use `IAsyncCommand` or `MvxAsyncCommand` or `AsyncCommand` or expose the command logic as an `async Task` method on the VM.

Comment: **FYI** I just checked your article about `IAsyncCommand` and there is a small bug in *Figure 11* in method `NotifyCommandStarting`. If the CTS is not cancelled then `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` will not be called but it has to be called.